# fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: PRIV

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket, pgp

When I do **git clone** or **git pull** or **git push** I receive the error

`fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: PRIV`

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your remote connection URI? Seems like you are trying to connect to the HTTP(S) endpoint via SSH? `git remote -v`

Comment: My remote is 

```
git remote -v
origin git@github.com:prest/prest.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:prest/prest.git (push)
```

Comment: it is not duplicate